# No matter what I do Podman is mounting volumes as root

Tags: containers, podman

I have configured Podman as user as I describe in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734790/240147)

In my dockerfile, I am going to great pains to absolutely ensure that the directory is owned by the user in question and have gone so far as to hardcode the values to be absolutely sure that it isn't a problem with environment variables while further deleting any group or user with node and then recreating them with that specific ID just to be extra extra certain:

```dockerfile
ARG USER_ID 1000
ARG GROUP_ID 1000
ARG GROUPNAME node
ARG USERNAME node

# getent group ${GROUP_ID} - Get the name of the group. Ex: `somegroup:x:999:`. This makes sure the group exists
# echo groupdel by-id ${GROUP_ID} - This is just there to tell the user what we're doing
# groupdel $(getent group ${GROUP_ID} | cut -d: -f1) - Gets the group string as above (`somegroup:x:999:`)
# and then passes it into `cut -d: -f1` which will grab the `somegroup` part and pass that into groupdel
# ||: The || is the or operator and : is the null operator. This just has the effect of ensuring the line
# returns with "success" rather than failure in the event the group doesn't exist
RUN (getent group ${GROUP_ID}  && (echo groupdel by-id ${GROUP_ID}; groupdel $(getent group ${GROUP_ID} | cut -d: -f1))) ||:
RUN (getent group ${GROUPNAME} && (echo groupdel ${GROUPNAME}; groupdel ${GROUPNAME})) ||:
RUN (getent passwd ${USERNAME} && (echo userdel ${USERNAME}; userdel -f ${USERNAME})) ||:
RUN groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} ${GROUPNAME}
RUN useradd -l -u ${USER_ID} -g ${GROUPNAME} ${USERNAME}

WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN mkdir /patches
RUN chown node:node /patches
```

This still didn't work, so in my build in docker-compose I further specified, explicitly, the permissions:

```yaml
  build:
    dockerfile: podman-build/Dockerfile.patches_backend
    args:
      USER_ID: ${USER_ID:-1000}
      GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID:-1000}
      USERNAME: node
      GROUPNAME: node
```

I don't know what else I'm missing, the UID/GID is correct in the container, the permissions of the folder outside the container are UID/GID=1000 as expected:

[image]

but this volume mount:

```yaml
volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: repos/xml
        target: /patches/xml
```

still stubbornly mounts in as root with UID/GID=0. I cannot for the life of me figure out where else it could be getting these permissions.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, you seem to be using docker compose somehow, but how you do that is unclear. Also, what user are you running stuff as? Include the output of `id`. Further, what OS are you on? I guess this is some Linux, but it wouldn't hurt mentioning that. Point is, that e.g. Docker on OS X does some funny things concerning permissions of files in volumes.

Comment: None of the above are relevant to the problem. I have determined the source - podman does not run the same way docker does. Docker uses fuse-ovelayfs to abstract file permissions on mounted volumes whereas (rootless) podman does not. Podman maps the uid/gid in the container to uid/gid 0 on the host by default. This means when volumes are mounted from the host they appear as being owned by uid/gid 0 in the container. I'll post a solution to the problem later today.

Comment: It's likely this [1]. I've been butting up against this issue also. podman-compose supports `userns_mode: keep-id` but docker-compose does not. There is also this thread [2] that talks about using `uidmap`.

[1]: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/options/userns.container.html
[2]: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/2898

Comment: I forgot to follow up, I fixed it, I'll post an answer now

Answer (score 3):

[This tutorial](https://www.tutorialworks.com/podman-rootless-volumes/) does a great job of explaining the problem. You have two options:

- Use `podman unshare` which will let you run commands in the same namespace as containers.
- Run as root inside the container (the container itself is still rootless)

`podman unshare` isn't great. The way that it works is you determine what UID is employed by the container and then you use `unshare` to set the ownership of the directory on the host filesystem to use that namespace. Problem is this requires you to change the owner on the host system which is rarely desirable and causes permissions issues.

The second approach is a lot better, albeit not from a security perspective - run as root inside the container and then mount the container with either `:Z` or `:z`. I'll let ChatGPT explain the difference between the two (it does a good job):

- "z" (Lowercase z): When a file or directory has the "z" context flag, it means that the object is labeled with a private unshared label. This is typically used for files or directories that are created by a process running inside a container. Objects with the "z" context are confined within the container and are not accessible to other containers or the host system.
- "Z" (Uppercase Z): On the other hand, the "Z" context flag is used for shared objects. Files or directories labeled with the "Z" flag are accessible to other containers and the host system. This flag allows multiple containers to share resources and access the same files or directories.

Ex:

```
podman run -it --rm --name nexus2 \
    -v /home/tom/myshares/nexus2:/sonatype-work:Z \
    -u root \
    sonatype/nexus /bin/sh
```

Hope this helps other people!

Comment: The linked tutorial was super helpful and clear. I think I'm disagreeing on the recommendation to not use `unshare`, though. To quote that article on that approach, "Running as root in the container is a bit more portable, but it’s cheating. We really shouldn’t be running anything as root, even inside a container. For this reason, this solution isn’t recommended for production setups."

Comment: If you can find a way to make it so that the mount retains its original permissions outside the container - I’m all onboard. I don’t disagree about root.

Comment: Don't trust ChatGPT
z = tells Podman that two or more containers share the volume content
Z = tells Podman to label the content with a private unshared label

Comment: Apologies, but I'm not sure I'm tracking how that is related. I'm familiar with the Z vs z option, but AFAIK that has no bearing on ownership of the files on the originating filesystem. It controls the visibility for other containers.

Comment: @GrantCurell your answer states the opposite for z and Z

Comment: Hmmmmm maybe I misunderstand something. I'm working on something else today - I'll look into it next week and see if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: HI Grant, the link was very useful. I have the same problem (mounted volume appears as root inside the container, but the container user is non-root, so can't access it). I can change the owner of the mounted directory using unshare as you suggest, but the problem is that I have another seperate container which also uses this volume. So changing the owner would mess up the second container. Do you have any advice that might help?

Comment: You have to run as root inside the container. You can’t use unshare then - at least I haven’t found a way to make that work

Answer (score 0):

Podman by default maps the host user id to the container root user id, meaning that any volumes mounted that is owned by the host user will be owned by root inside the container. You can change this by providing the --userns option as described here:
https://docs.podman.io/en/v4.6.1/markdown/options/userns.container.html#userns-mode